# Merging combinations of counts from a groupby() in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a df that has been created through grouping on Principal Investigators and the possible ethics boards in research who could approve their applications. I then count the rows via the size() method. This gives me the number of trials a PI has per ethics board.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"principal_investigator": ["Tiger Woods", "Tiger Woods", "Buzz Lightyear", "Maggie Thatcher", "Maggie Thatcher", "Seamus Heaney"],
     "board": ["CREB", "BCCA", "CREB", "CWEB", "BCCA", "CREB"],
     "counts": [2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df

    principal_investigator  board   counts
0   Tiger Woods             CREB    2
1   Tiger Woods             BCCA    1
2   Buzz Lightyear          CREB    2
3   Maggie Thatcher         CWEB    3
4   Maggie Thatcher         BCCA    1
5   Seamus Heaney           CREB    1
```

But I want a count of the combinations of (board, counts). Something like below for better visual result for my boss to review.

```
    principal_investigator  board_counts
0   Tiger Woods             (CREB 2, BCCA 1)                
1   Buzz Lightyear          CREB    2
2   Maggie Thatcher         (CWEB 3, BCCA 1)
3   Seamus Heaney           CREB    1
```

Open to suggestions on a better way to combine these better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the style of table you are requesting:

```
>>> df.groupby('principal_investigator').apply(lambda x: dict(x[['board', 'counts']].values))

principal_investigator
Buzz Lightyear                {'CREB': 2}
Maggie Thatcher    {'CWEB': 3, 'BCCA': 1}
Seamus Heaney                 {'CREB': 1}
Tiger Woods        {'CREB': 2, 'BCCA': 1}
```

You can also use the .groupby() with multiple columns to get a stacked combination.

```
>>> result = df.groupby(['principal_investigator', 'board'])['counts'].sum()
>>> result

principal_investigator  board
Buzz Lightyear          CREB     2
Maggie Thatcher         BCCA     1
                        CWEB     3
Seamus Heaney           CREB     1
Tiger Woods             BCCA     1
                        CREB     2
```

If you want the underlying pivot table, as Corralien has presented, you can use .unstack() on the result:

```
>>> result.unstack()

board                   BCCA  CREB  CWEB
principal_investigator
Buzz Lightyear           NaN   2.0   NaN
Maggie Thatcher          1.0   NaN   3.0
Seamus Heaney            NaN   1.0   NaN
Tiger Woods              1.0   2.0   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you an alternative presentation:

```py
>>> pd.crosstab(df1["principal_investigator"], df1["board"],
                df1["counts"], aggfunc="sum").fillna(0).astype(int)

board                   BCCA  CREB  CWEB
principal_investigator
Buzz Lightyear             0     2     0
Maggie Thatcher            1     0     3
Seamus Heaney              0     1     0
Tiger Woods                1     2     0
```

To answer your question (well almost):

```
>>> df["board"].str.cat(df["counts"].astype(str), sep=" ") \
               .groupby(df["principal_investigator"]) \
               .apply(", ".join) \
               .to_frame("board_counts")

                          board_counts
principal_investigator
Buzz Lightyear                  CREB 2
Maggie Thatcher         CWEB 3, BCCA 1
Seamus Heaney                   CREB 1
Tiger Woods             CREB 2, BCCA 1
```

Comment: That's great but what if my manager say wanted a very quick and rough breakdown with the tuple or even a dictionary breakdown, how could I go about merging the columns ("BCCA", "CREB", "CWEB")  so that I had a breakdown like Tiger Woods {"BCCA": 1, "CREB": 2}

Comment: Thanks very much, very good effort. .cat is a new one for me. I will.